# PHP - Displaying multiple years from the current year

Tags: php

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I want to display a dropdown ( select ) box with 10 years starting with the current year.

I know displaying the year is done by using

```
date("Y");
```

But im not sure how to display the 10 years after that automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Are you familiar with loops and the `+` operator?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
    echo('<select name="year">');
    for ( $i = date("Y"); $i < date("Y")+11; $i++ )
    {
      echo('<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>');
    }
    echo('</select>');
```

See result here http://codepad.viper-7.com/8S0Ogi

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a slew of [Date/Time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) functions.

One you have instantiated a [DateTime Object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php), you'll be able to manipulate any date or time using simple [`date_add`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) or [`date_sub`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) functions...

---

However, for your situation, it would be possible and a lot simpler to simply iterate over the number of years you want in the dropdown and simply increase the value for each option.

```
$yearSpan = 10;
$currentYear = date("Y");
$html = '<select id="foobar">';
for($i = $currentYear; $i<=$yearSpan; $i++) {
  $html .= "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
}
$html .= '</select>';
```

That should populate `$html` with content similar to this -

```
<select id="foobar">
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  ...
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  <option value="2022">2022</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
<select>
    <option>Select One</option>
    <?php 
        $year = date("Y");
        $yearto = date("Y")+10;
        while ($year <= $yearto)
        {
            echo "<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>";
            $year++;
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: This would **visually** be fine - but without `value` attributes for the `<option>` elements, not much could be accomplished with it...